# PHP - Latin Characters from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having a rather strange problem:
I am working with a database (which I did not design), this database is multi-lingual, that is, there are titles in English, Spanish, Russian, Vietnamese, etc.

From what I have seen titles with characters of type "ñ", "á", "é", "ë", have been stored in the database in this way: "&ntilde_", so I know in html for show these characters how to write them is "`&ntilde;`" in my PHP code at the time of calling these characters (without using any type of conversion) the following happens to me:

```
Title in database: Se&ntilde_ora // Señora
Title obtained by PHP: Señ_ora // Señora
```

I tried using utf_decode and html_entities_decode but this did not work.
I wanted to do this, use a str_replace to remove the "_" from the title "Señ_ora" but I got: "Se&ntildeora"

Comment: in mysql for column fields set utf 8 general ci in collation

Comment: MYSQL database UTF8 general-ci before insert in PHP charset utf8 and dont need to add why you try to do, regards.

Comment: Where does the underscore come from? These are invalid entities.

Comment: For some reason the database changes the semi-colon by the underscore. I'm trying to change the encoding to utf_general but I'm getting an error and I think it's because I already have a fulltext created with that column.

Comment: UTF8 won't make a difference. Your entities are invalid, you need to fix that. The DB wouldn't change a `;` to an `_`. You need to look at how you are inserting. If you convert to utf8 you could change all the entities to their actual characters.

Comment: I am positive that neither PHP nor MySQL turned `;` into `_`.  Dig further back in the source of the text.

Comment: I think they might have put "_" instead of ";" because I know the information was originally in a CSV file and maybe not to interfere with the delimiter ";", they used "_" to store it. It is a teory but what if it is safe is that I can not change via query all values because this table have more than 6,000,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> characters of type "ñ", "á", "é", "ë", have been stored in the database in this way: "&ntilde_"

This is bizarre.

First of all, make sure your database actually contains these `_` characters, and make sure you're not seeing some sort of substitution character being rendered. Whatever program you're using to show the data might have some character set option set incorrectly.

You might say `SELECT field, HEX(field) FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%' ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(field) LIMIT 10`  to find a few relatively short examples. Then pore over the hex output looking for `3B` (hex for `;`) and `5F` (hex for `_`).

For example,  `SELECT HEX('Se&ntilde;ora'), HEX('Se&ntilde_ora')` on my UTF8 setup gives these two strings

```
5365266E74696C64653B6F7261
                  xx
5365266E74696C64655F6F7261
```

See the difference?

If the `_` characters are definitely in your data, you have some cyber-speklunking to do. Do you have access to the person who set this up, so you can ask about it? If so, do. It will save you some reverse-engineering time.

If you have to fix this without help, you can try using php like this

```
 $my_data = str_replace('_',';', $my_data);
```

That should get the entitized characters to be formatted correctly. **But**, it will also change standalone `_` characters to `;`.  To fix this right, you'll need a list of all the entitized characters in your data, and you'll need to change them individually.

Comment: I made the checks that you proposed to me but in the end the simplest solution was to replace "_" with ";".
Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, @Kokox.  If you figure out how this happened to your data, could you please edit your question or post a comment explaining it? Your experience might help other people.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding You ca also handle this while connecting/making a connection with mysql using PHP code .

// Make sure data is UTF*, that way database can see accents and stuff

```
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("dbname");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET 'utf8'", $db);
```

Comment: Do _not_ use the `mysql_*` interface in PHP.  Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.